# bootstrap columns width issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Well, I customize column width to 75px.

if I have this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span1">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the column has the correct width, but if I have this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="span1">some text</div>
</div>
```

the column has different width.

Comment: Some relevant CSS code or link to your site will be usefull

Comment: i think class="row-fluid" css is there

Comment: Try to provide a jsfiddle too please.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `.row-fluid .span*` width is a percentage.
If you resize the window browser, you will see that column width changes, in this case span1.

To hold always 75px to span1, put in your custom css

```
.row-fluid .span1{
    width: 75px !important;
    *width: 75px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid system usually follow a strict hierarchy for creating layouts.

Twitter bootstrap expects all your columns to be kept inside rows. CSS written for bootstrap uses descendant selectors according to hierarchy that you have given. So if you change the hierarchy, rules which are going to be applied will be different.

Following extract from bootstrap css can put some light on same.

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    //Other properties removed for readability
}

.row-fluid .span12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.94680851063829%;
}

.row-fluid .span11 {
    width: 91.48936170212765%;
    *width: 91.43617021276594%;
}

.row-fluid .span10 {
    width: 82.97872340425532%;
    *width: 82.92553191489361%;
}

.row-fluid .span9 {
    width: 74.46808510638297%;
    *width: 74.41489361702126%;
}

.row-fluid .span8 {
    width: 65.95744680851064%;
    *width: 65.90425531914893%;
}

.row-fluid .span7 {
    width: 57.44680851063829%;
    *width: 57.39361702127659%;
}

.row-fluid .span6 {
    width: 48.93617021276595%;
    *width: 48.88297872340425%;
}

.row-fluid .span5 {
    width: 40.42553191489362%;
    *width: 40.37234042553192%;
}

.row-fluid .span4 {
    width: 31.914893617021278%;
    *width: 31.861702127659576%;
}

.row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 23.404255319148934%;
    *width: 23.351063829787233%;
}

.row-fluid .span2 {
    width: 14.893617021276595%;
    *width: 14.840425531914894%;
}

.row-fluid .span1 {
    width: 6.382978723404255%;
    *width: 6.329787234042553%;
}
```